# Monitoramento de uso de ferramenta de busca

Tags: php, html, input, algoritmo-de-busca, monitoramento

No site do meu cliente, existe uma espécie de ferramenta de busca. Essa busca exige que o usuário escolha qual das seções (páginas) ele quer buscar. Com a palavra desejada e a seção escolhida, ele redireciona pra página e traz os resultados de busca desejados.

Por exemplo, se eu quiser pesquisar algo na Central de Downloads, a página normalmente é:
meusite.com.br/servicos/centraldownloads/

Mas se eu usar a ferramenta de busca:
meusite.com.br/busca/6/

O que eu queria saber é como eu posso e se é possível monitorar quantas pessoas estão indo pra essas páginas através da busca (páginas que começam com meusite.com.br/busca).

A outra coisa que imagino se poderia fazer um monitoramento é através do botão BUSCAR dessa ferramenta de busca, ela possui o seguinte código HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="BtnBuscar replace-bt" value="">
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; nas paginas. e verifique se contem meusite.com.br/busca

Comment: e essas quantas pessoas guardaria aonde? BD, arquivo txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paginas monitoradas

```
$result = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$pos = strpos($result, "meusite.com.br/busca");
    if ($pos !== false) {
        // script .....  
    }
```

> Esse log do referer é usado para permitir que sites web e servidores web identifiquem de onde as pessoas o estão visitando, ou seja, pela verificação do referer, a nova página web pode ver de onde a requisição se originou. (Em suma: saber de onde o usuário veio, qual página que ele estava que o mandou para a nova pagina).

Comment: Sabe me informar se essa mesma função pode ser feita em javascript?

Comment: document.referrer

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma é usar $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; e armazenar no Banco de dados, ai voce pode usar PDO normalmente. ex:

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tabela SET val = valor");
$sql->execute();
```